# Importar uma tabela Excel para o GeneXus

Tags: microsoft-excel, genexus

Comecei a mexer recentemente com GeneXus devido ao meu estágio, preciso passar as informações de uma planilha Excel para o GX para usar no BD.

Estou ciente de um pattern que faz isso, mas ele ainda está em beta e só tem compatibilidade até certa versão do GX 15, e estou recentemente utilizando a Trial 16.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia. Você pode ler a planilha Excel com comandos de programação Genexus e ir alimentado sua tabela no banco de dados.
A programação é feita a partir da criação de uma variável do tipo ExcelDocument. Para você ter ideia veja dois materiais:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33755,Generating+Excel+and+Word+Documents+%28X+Evolution+3%29,

http://treinamentodash.blogspot.com/2008/05/upload-de-arquivos-e-leitura-de-arquivo.html

Isso já vai te dar uma base. Surgindo as dúvidas, poste novamente que te ajudo.

Bom trabalho!

Comment: Os guias são bons, mas não exatamente o que preciso, um deles é sobre gerar documentos XML com o GX, o outro para ler tabelas sem usar o MS Office. Eu tenho uma tabela XML com informações que gostaria de usar poderia inseri-las manualmente na KB mas isso tomaria muito tempo, por isso gostaria de inseri-las diretamente, parecido com o que é mostrado nesse vídeo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVvcbS72y_A) 
Claro que não preciso que seja tão prático assim, mas algo semelhante

Comment: Ola Vinicius, me mostre seu codigo para leitura da planilha Excel. Assim posso te ajudar melhor.